# jQuery sortable with AJAX only works every other time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got a table of fields that have a drag-to-sort handle using jQuery's sortable plugin which in turn fires a PHP script via AJAX to save the changes once a submit button is clicked.  However, it only actually works on average every other time.  Every once and a while I'll get two successful runs back-to-back but that's pretty rare.

Here's my HTML, dynamically generated:

```
<div class="foldertable">
  <table class="data" id="sortable">
    <tr class="odd" id="field_21">
      <td class="handle"><a href="/admin/database/customfields/edit?cfid=21">Occupant Name</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even" id="field_22">
      <td class="handle"><a href="/admin/database/customfields/edit?cfid=22">DBA</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd" id="field_23">
      <td class="handle"><a href="/admin/database/customfields/edit?cfid=23">Tenant Contact</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <a href="" id="button" class="textbutton">Update Order</a>
</div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
        ui.children().each(function() {
            $(this).width($(this).width());
        });
        return ui;
    };
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sortable tbody").sortable({ 
            helper: fixHelper,
            opacity: 0.6, 
            update: function(){
                $('#savemessage').html('<p>Click <em>update order</em> to save</p>');
                $('#button').show();
                }
        });
        $('#button').click(function(event){
            var order = $("#sortable tbody").sortable("serialize");
            order += "&crudtype=order";
            $('#savemessage').html('<p>Saving changes...</p>');
            $.post("/admin/database/customfields/crud",order,function(theResponse){
                    $('#savemessage').html(theResponse);
                });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And the resulting PHP page, /admin/database/customfields/crud

```
$fields = $_POST['field'];
$counter = 1;
foreach ($fields as $field) {
  $params = array(array('value' => $counter, 'type' => 'i'), array('value' => $field, 'type' => 'i'));
  db_query('UPDATE customfields SET sortorder = ? WHERE cfid = ?', $params, false);
  $counter++;
}
print '<p>Changes saved</p>';
exit(); // Exit necessary for AJAX call
break; // End reorder
```

I based this off of this site, http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-ui/, and it does work -- just not every time.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code and re-created your module and it works fine everytime.
Based on this the only things I can conclude that maybe the PHP page is served from the cache? Could you check the header of 'resulting PHP page'?
The easiest is to use something like Firefox's Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools to monitor the network traffic and check the ajax call and the PHP response.

EDIT:
I realized that your issue is that the UPDATE ORDER text is an A HREF link, so when the user clicks on it that instructs the browser to reload the page - so sometimes it reloads it before it would fire out the AJAX call. Just change your A HREF to a DIV or SPAN and it will work.

So instead of

```
<a href="" id="button" class="textbutton">Update Order</a>
```

have

```
<div id="button" class="textbutton">Update Order</div>
```

or

```
<span id="button" class="textbutton">Update Order</span>
```

Comment: I'd be happy to provide that though I'm not sure how to do that through Firebug.  How can you get the header of an AJAX called page?  Or, if there's some way to force a non-cached version I could do that but I don't know what command that would be.

Comment: First install Firebug in Firefox. Then open your page and then enable Firebug. Then make the changes on the page by re-sorting the items and click the update. In Firebug's Network section you will see the request going out. Also you need to modify your code a little, because the Update Order link is an "a href", so when you click on it that will reload the page. Hups. I think I just realized that this is what is probably causing your issue. The A HREF reloads the page before the AJAX would fire. So just change A HREF to a DIV or a SPAN and it will work 100% of the times.

Comment: That did it -- thanks a bunch, and thanks for the tip about the network section.  I use Firebug all the time but have never checked that tab.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. For AJAX development looking at the network communication from the browser is a must - otherwise you are lost. Honestly I lately use Chrome's Developer Tools more, it has the same Network option. Firefox's Firebug has more features, but lately I mostly develop based on Chrome, so it is just easier to use the tool in there.

Comment: Instead of changing the button to a div or span, you can just return false on the click event.

This is semantically correct and <a>'s also have a `cursor: pointer` on them by default.